# How to retrieve an http request headers item from a symbol map?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, graphql, symbols, apollo-server

I am trying to retrieve a particular request header from an apolloserver request (i.e. the *request* object from a *GraphQLRequestContext*), inside a a plugin.

logging the `headers` object logs out as:

```
Headers {
  [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] {
    'content-type': [ 'application/json' ],
    user: [
      '{...(redacted)...}'
    ],
    'x-header-foo': [ '234' ],
    accept: [ '*/*' ],
    'content-length': [ '256' ],
    'user-agent': [ 'node-fetch/1.0 (+https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch)' ],
    'accept-encoding': [ 'gzip,deflate' ],
    connection: [ 'close' ],
    host: [ 'localhost:3000' ]
  }
}
```

but `headers['x-header-foo']` yields undefined. How do I get the header value? I have not used symbols much so far.

Comment: Which middleware are you using? "*the `request` object from a `GraphQLRequestContext`*" can be [multiple things](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/apollo-server/#middleware-specific-context-fields).

Comment: Try logging `Object.getPrototoypeOf(request.headers)`. Probably the object you've logged has methods like `.get()`.

Comment: omg... i didn't see get() listed - but .get('x-header-foo') worked! Thx!!!

Answer (score 0):

As you said rightly, Headers are Symbols and not Objects, so to get value, you use the get method

[Read more about Symbols here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) Symbol is a built-in object whose constructor returns a symbol primitive — also called a Symbol value or just a Symbol — that's guaranteed to be unique.

Headers are Symbols and not Objects, so to get value, you use the get method

```
const host = req.headers.get("host"); // stackoverflow.com
```

If you wish to destructure using Symbols:

```
let symbol = Symbol()
let obj = { [symbol] : 'value'}
let { [symbol]: alias } = obj

console.log(alias)
```

Comment: "*Headers are Symbols and not Objects*" - no